# Signing an NDA not on Behalf of a Company

Tags: contract-law

I have been provided an NDA that I need to sign. I am not affiliated with a company, however, and am just a freelancer with a fulltime job.

- At the top of the NDA, I need to fill out my 'company/party'. Should I just use my name, or the name of my full-time company?
- The bottom has a blank line, again for party/company. Should I just fill in my name, sign next to the "By" line and leave the "Its" line blank?

Comment: I suggest you call and ask the guy that provided you with the NDA to sign.

Answer (score 1):

Don't leave anything blank. At least put N/A in the space.

So your name goes at the top and

> Company: N/A   By:*your signature*   Its: N/A

goes at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of an NDA is to bind the two parties.  The correct answer is to sign it in any way that satisfies both you and the counterparty.

In general, if you are a party to a contract as an individual, and someone hands you a stock contract designed for entities, either of the following should be acceptable:

1. Sign it as an individual.  You can leave fields applicable to entities blank, cross them out; it doesn't matter.
2. You can present yourself as an entity.  As a 1099 (in the U.S.) freelance contractor, at the very least you are a "Sole Proprietor."  You can declare yourself to be President or whatever title you want of your sole proprietorship.  You can name your proprietorship (so long as you don't claim any entity type you have not established, like a Corporation, and so long as your name doesn't infringe somebody's trademark).  Whatever floats your boat!